# java - How to display per partition in kafka rather than per record?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, partition, consumer

I am currently building a `kafka` consumer in java where it would only display the partitions (I have 10 partitions) and offsets of a specific `topic` and `group id`. My current code displays per record (or per row data) of the given input. If I have 10 partitions and 15 rows of data it would display 15 rows and multiple instances of the partition.

Here are my settings for the consumer:

```
private static Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {
    System.out.println("CREATE CONSUMER");
    //Configure consumer settings/properties
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUPID);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

    // Create the consumer using props.
    final Consumer<Long, String> consumer =  new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

    // Subscribe to the topic.
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));
    return consumer;
}
```

Here is my code for the displaying of output:

```
while (noRecordsCount < giveUp)
    {
        final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(500);

        if (consumerRecords.count() == 0)
        {
            noRecordsCount++;
            if (noRecordsCount > giveUp) break;
            else continue;
        }          

        //Stores each topic and partition to a specific array list for easier output manipulation
        consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
            partitionrecord.add(record.partition());
            offsetrecord.add(record.offset());
            System.out.printf("Consumer Record: %s (%d, %d)"+"\n", TOPIC, record.partition(), record.offset()); 

        });

    }
```

Code output :

[image]

Expected output is showing an instance per partition not per record (topic name, partition number, offset) :

[image]

What I need to do is to display 10 partitions rather than displaying each (15) record and its specific information (offset, partition, value, etc.). do I need to add any specific commands or functions in my code? I am new to stack overflow and I apologize if my inquiry is long.

Comment: Can you please include an example of the output you expect?

Comment: I've edited my post to show the expected output per partition and not per record.

Answer (score 0):

You're always going to get all records following the latest offset you started from, and for all partitions assigned to the consumer instance.

If you run ten consumers, you should expect to only see one partition per instance, but still all offsets.

There is no setting to only get one record, as that's up to your producers to only send N messages evenly after the consumer starts waiting for them.

There is also no guarantee of ordering across partitions for a consumer instance with more than one partition assigned to it

---

You could, however, use a TreeMap or a max-heap data structure to store your data points, then loop over the partitions in order and output the max consumed offsets for each

In other words, you're currently printing out every record, and not printing after the all loops over the partitions, therefore you get the first shown output

So, there's no way to do what you want "in Kafka", but the problem you're asking about is really a matter of how you batch the records as you're getting them, then storing only the maximum, and finally where you output that information.

Note: the `GetOffsetShell` command can already query the greatest current offset for all partitions